# Are the release:prepare goal's steps sufficient?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I have a question about the Maven Release plugin. According to the plugin documentation, one of the steps followed by the release:prepare goal is :

- Check that there are no uncommitted changes in the sources.

I understand the importance of this point. Let's take as example the case of a multimodules project developed by many developers. Every developer has done its part of the work, and the project is ready to be released. But, only one person on one machine will do the release, and I think that checking the presence of uncommitted changes in the working copy of the person performing the release isn't enough.

Maybe there are uncommitted changes in the working copies of other developer that also worked on the project? Am I missing something (I mean, is this really a problem? If yes, is there a way to do these verifications with Maven or the working copies of the other developers must be checked manually?)

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't do it on a developer machine anyway ... I would use a build server for that purpose, and this should always do a fresh checkout (or at least a revert in the case of Subversion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it checks for uncommitted changes in the sources is so that the released binary corresponds to the source code in the repository.

If there were uncommitted changes on the machine doing the release, then the binaries wouldn't correspond to the source.

If other developers have uncommitted changes, that doesn't matter, because their changes won't end up in the binary.

Comment: Okay, but these changes may be part of the release. I mean, if one developer have worked on a feature specific to this release, its changes will not be taken into account, and this is a wrong release, because it doesn't contain this feature. So, I don't understand why it doesn't matter?

Comment: Yeah but you'll be able to figure that out by inspecting the source code. Like I said, the reason for the check is to ensure the binary matches the repository source, nothing more.

Comment: Okay, but my question is then, is there an automatic way to do these verifications? I mean to check if working copies of the other developers are entirely committed.

Comment: I doubt it. Such a plugin would have to know an awful lot about the developers of the project and their working copies. What if there was some uncommitted code on a computer that's currently switched off? 

In most places, the lead developer will say 'We're doing a release on [date] at [time], make sure you're committed your code by then' or words to that effect.